# How can I change the logo color by scrolling DIVs with specific classes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently working on a project where the logo color should change depending on the background color. I would prefer to do this with CSS classes.

Unfortunately, the problem is: As soon as the first DIV of the class "bg02" is scrolled, the class changes for the logo too, but as soon as the following "bg02" divs are scrolled, nothing happens anymore. What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?

Here's my code:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#logo').each(function() {
        var currDiv = $(this);
        var refElement = $('.bg02');
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#logo').removeClass("inverted");
        currDiv.addClass("inverted");
        } else {
        currDiv.removeClass("inverted");
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 100;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
}

#logo.inverted {
    color: #fff;
}

.bg01, .bg02 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.bg01 {
    background: #fff;
}

.bg02 {
    background: #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo">Logo</div>


<div class="bg01"></div>

<div class="bg02"></div>

<div class="bg01"></div>

<div class="bg02"></div>

<div class="bg01"></div>

<div class="bg02"></div>
```

Comment: You have `$("#logo").removeClass` but your `currDiv` == `$("#logo")` - so you remove the class then immediately add it back.  As they'll always be only one element in `$("#logo")` you don't need the `.each`, which may help you.

Comment: Your issue is that `$('.bg02').position()` can only return a single position, so it returns the position for the first one.  To use this method, you need to loop `.bg02` not `#logo`  Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/6oranpxy/

Comment: Oh man, you just solved that so quickly and i'm sitting here blind for hours. Thanks so much! Shame on me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `$('.bg02').position()` can only return a single position, so it returns the position for the first one.

To use your method of checking scrollTop(), you need to loop `.bg02` not `#logo`

Couple of small changes to your code:

Loop `.bg02`:

```
$('.bg02').each(function() {
  var refElement = $(this);
```

and a "break" inside the `if` - `return false` to stop the loop continuing and removing the inverted class for the later .bg02 that doesn't match

```
if (positioncheck) {
  $("#logo").addClass("inverted");
  return false;
}
```

You can also "tweak" when the logo gets inverted by considering its position, eg:

```
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop() 
                  + $("#logo").position().top 
                  + ($("#logo").height() / 2)
```

as it was, it would only invert when bg02 got to the top.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop() 
                  + $("#logo").position().top 
                  + ($("#logo").height() / 2)
  $('.bg02').each(function() {
    var refElement = $(this);
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos 
        && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
      $('#logo').addClass("inverted");
      // found one, so exit .each
      return false;
    } else {
      $('#logo').removeClass("inverted");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 100;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
}

#logo.inverted {
    color: #fff;
}

.bg01, .bg02 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

.bg01 {
    background: #fff;
}

.bg02 {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">Logo</div>
<div class="bg01"></div>
<div class="bg02"></div>
<div class="bg01"></div>
<div class="bg02"></div>
<div class="bg01"></div>
<div class="bg02"></div>
```

Comment: Thats an awesome solution. Thanks! Theres only one thing that doesn't work. If the background DIV has padding and/or margin, than the Logo change too early in and out. Maybe it seems that the refElement.height() would need an offsetHeight? But that also doesn't work. Can you help last time?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but could you help me one last time? It's only the thing that it doesn't work perfect if the background DIV has margin/padding. I still didn't get it to work.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question, you can use this answer (or what you've derived from it) as a basis.  You'll be more likely to get a useful response.